# How to fix "unknown column" error in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm getting this error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed_at` = '2020-02-29 19:14:22', `updated_at` = '2020-02-29 19:14:22' WHERE `users`.`` IS NULL
```

after I click on the link sent by Devise to my email. I have no idea how to handle this since I have no power on the query. I'm wondering if I'm forgetting something.

I overwrote the confirmation controller, but I didn't write anything inside it yet.

The flow is:

- Login with Google.
- Send the link.
- Click the link => Error.

This is the `Users` schema:

```
create_table "users", id: false, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "usercode"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "drivlicense_nr"
    t.string "birth_nation", limit: 2
    t.string "tpoliceman_id"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "encrypted_password"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "refresh_token"
    t.string "token"
    t.boolean "expires"
    t.integer "expires_at"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
    t.index ["usercode"], name: "index_users_on_usercode", unique: true
  end
```

This is the migration:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
      create_table :users, primary_key: :email, id: false do |t|
          t.integer   :usercode
          t.boolean   :admin, default: false
          t.string    :drivlicense_nr
          t.string    :birth_nation, limit: 2
          t.string    :tpoliceman_id

          ## Database authenticatable
          t.string    :email
          t.string    :encrypted_password

          ## Recoverable
          t.string    :reset_password_token
          t.datetime  :reset_password_sent_at

          ## Rememberable
          t.datetime  :remember_created_at

          ## Trackable
          t.integer   :sign_in_count, null: false, default: 0
          t.datetime  :current_sign_in_at
          t.datetime  :last_sign_in_at
          t.string    :current_sign_in_ip
          t.string    :last_sign_in_ip

          ## Confirmable
          t.string    :confirmation_token
          t.datetime  :confirmed_at
          t.datetime  :confirmation_sent_at
          t.string    :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
          #t.datetime  :updated_at

          ## Omniauthable
          t.string    :provider
          t.string    :uid
          t.string    :refresh_token
          t.string    :token
          t.boolean   :expires
          t.integer   :expires_at

          ## Lockable
          t.integer   :failed_attempts,                      null: false, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
          t.string    :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
          t.datetime  :locked_at

          t.timestamps null: false
      end

      add_index :users, :usercode,             unique: true
      add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
      add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
      add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
      add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
      #add_index :users, %i[drivlicense_nr birth_nation], name: 'index_users_on_person'#, unique: true
      # validates :drivlicense_nr, uniqueness: { scope: :birth_nation }
  end
end
```

This is the whole error printed in the console:

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=vS2uK-SfvxW9XhrTMULA" for ::1 at 2020-02-29 19:24:17 +0100
Processing by Users::ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"vS2uK-SfvxW9XhrTMULA"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'vS2uK-SfvxW9XhrTMULA' LIMIT 1
  ↳ /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Update (2.4ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed_at` = '2020-02-29 19:24:17', `updated_at` = '2020-02-29 19:24:17' WHERE `users`.`` IS NULL
  ↳ /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)



ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed_at` = '2020-02-29 19:24:17', `updated_at` = '2020-02-29 19:24:17' WHERE `users`.`` IS NULL):

mysql2 (0.5.3) lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
mysql2 (0.5.3) lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `block in query'
mysql2 (0.5.3) lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `handle_interrupt'
mysql2 (0.5.3) lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `query'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:187:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:186:in `block in execute'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:581:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:580:in `block in log'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:571:in `log'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:185:in `execute'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:28:in `execute'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:196:in `execute_and_free'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:45:in `exec_delete'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:170:in `update'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:21:in `update'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:197:in `_update_record'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:696:in `_update_row'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:80:in `_update_row'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:719:in `_update_record'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:134:in `_update_record'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:350:in `block in _update_record'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_update_callbacks'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:350:in `_update_record'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:114:in `_update_record'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:705:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:342:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:275:in `save'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:46:in `save'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:325:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:309:in `save'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
devise (4.7.1) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:97:in `block in confirm'
devise (4.7.1) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:239:in `pending_any_confirmation'
devise (4.7.1) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:80:in `confirm'
devise (4.7.1) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:373:in `confirm_by_token'
devise (4.7.1) app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:23:in `show'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.4.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.4.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.2.4.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.3) lib/puma/server.rb:674:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.3) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.3) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you paste the schema of your `users` table?

Comment: Edited the post right now. Sorry!

Comment: Hope you have added :confirmable module inside user.rb and verify the same by checking it on your rails console by typing... User.first.confirmed?, if that works, then surely there is some problem with your tables.

Comment: `WHERE \`users\`.\`\` IS NULL` looks wrong. The query is looking for a column/field name that is `NULL` but no column is defined.

Comment: @Milind Yes `:confirmable` is inside user.rb, for sure, it's not the first time that i'm using it. 
Anyway, I used User.first.confirmed? inside the console when i get displayed the error and the result is actually false.
@theTinMan the problem is why it goes for something like users."" i don't understand why it's empty. I have no idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I recreated from scratch the basic flow for devise mailer. I checked what the query was looking for and I noticed it wanted `users.id`. By looking inside my migration I found that I put `id:false` because I was overwriting a primary_key.